# SQL Multiple INNER JOINS In One Select-Statement

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am using this code for inventory management system, in which i want to retrieve stock in hand from four tables. i have tried with two table and got accurate result as i need it.please help me out.

Table Schema

**Productmastertb**

```
prod_id,
Product_name
```

**salesdetailstb**

```
sales_id,
Prod_id,
Prod_qty
```

**estimatedetailstb**

```
est_id,
Prod_id,
Prod_qty
```

**Purchasedetailstb**

```
est_id,
Prod_id,
Prod_qty
```

Query example (working):

```
SELECT
    productmastertb.prod_id, 
    productmastertb.prod_name, 
    sum(estimatedetailstd.prod_qty) as Est_qty 
FROM 
    productmaster 
INNER JOIN 
    estimatedetailstb ON productmastertb.prodid = estimatedetails.prodid 
GROUP BY 
    productmastertb.prod_id, productmastertb.prod_name
```

Similarly I have to retrieve sum of salesdetailstb.qty and purchasedetailstb.qty

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to summarize across different "dimensions" -- that is tables.  One good approach is to aggregate *before* doing the `JOIN`s.  Or to use subqueries.  Here is the latter approach:

```
SELECT pm.prod_id, pm.prod_name, 
       (SELECT SUM(ed.prod_qty)
        FROM estimatedetailstb as ed
        WHERE ed.prodid = ed.prodidas
       ) as Est_qty,
       (SELECT SUM(sd.prod_qty)
        FROM salesdetailstb as sd
        WHERE sd.prodid = pm.prodidas
       ) as Sales_qty,
       (SELECT SUM(pd.prod_qty)
        FROM purchasedetailstb as pd
        WHERE pd.prodid = pm.prodid
       ) as Sales_qty
FROM productmaster pm;
```

This will give you all products, even those missing from one or more of the other tables.

Comment: wow! that's great, got accurate result as i need it, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple joins.

```
SELECT t1.id, t4.name, count(t4.name) 
FROM Table1 AS t1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 -- the AS statement renames the table within
                            -- this query to t2. Columns from this table can be used 
                            -- as t2.columnname. This needs to be done when you have 
                            -- columns with the same name in different tables.
        ON t1.id = t2.id
    INNER JOIN Table3 as t3
        ON t1.id = t3.id
    INNER JOIN Table4 as t4
        ON t3.name = t4.name
GROUP BY t1.id, t4.name
```

Comment: not working. got same error "SYNTAX ERROR (Missing operator)" in query expression